# OnGUI Health Bar Scaling

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to set up a health bar for a 2D game using OnGUI. I have an outside texture and an inside texture for the meter. The set up I have now works partially. I am able to change the scale of the inside meter so it looks like it is depleting, however the position  along the x is changing as well. This causes an awkward effect as well as the meter moving outside its container.

```
void Update ()
{
    score = EnemyScript.killCount * 100;
    powerScale -= 1; 
}

void OnGUI()
{
    //Score and Power Containter
    GUILayout.BeginArea(new Rect(Screen.width/8, Screen.height/8, 500, 200));
    GUILayout.Label("Score: " + score, style);
    GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(-10,20,200,80),powerBoundry);
    GUILayout.EndArea();
    //Power Meter
    GUILayout.BeginArea(new Rect(Screen.width/8, Screen.height/8, 450, 200));
    GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(-10,20,powerScale,80),powerFill, ScaleMode.ScaleAndCrop);
    GUILayout.EndArea();
}
```

Is it possible to anchor it in place? Or perhaps make it a child of a game object to anchor it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using DrawTextureWithTexCoords.

```
void OnGUI()
{
    GUILayout.BeginArea(new Rect(Screen.width / 8, Screen.height / 8, 500, 200));
    GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(-10, 20, 200, 80), powerBoundry);
    GUI.DrawTextureWithTexCoords(new Rect(-10, 20, powerScale, 80), powerFill, new Rect(0f, 0f, (float)powerScale / 200f, 1f));
    GUILayout.EndArea();
}
```